# why the finite Fourier sine transform use integral and the inverse use summation?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

> The finite Fourier sine transform of $f(x),0<x<l$ is defined as, $$f_s(n)=\int_0^lf(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}\:dx$$
> And the inverse finite Fourier sine transform of $f_s(n)$ is defined as, $$f(x)=\frac{2}{l}\sum_{n=l}^\infty f_s(n)\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}$$

Okay, I have some intuition about Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform. Even their formula seems very similar, $$F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\:dt$$
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\:d\omega$$

But, when I see finite Fourier sine transform, and it's inverse, I couldn't understand why the transform use integral and the inverse use summation. Is there any interpretation of that?

Comment: The "Fourier sine transform" that you're referring to is a version of the [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series). It might be better to compare the Fourier transform to the complex version of the Fourier series, whereby
$$
f_s(n) = \int_0^l f(x) e^{2 \pi i x/l}\,dx
$$

Comment: One very coarse interpretation of the discrepancy is that a function over a finite interval requires only a countable "amount of information", while a function over $\Bbb R$ requires an uncountable amount. A more precise version of this might be a presentation of the Fourier transform as a limit of Fourier series. You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45883/81360) to be helpful

Comment: A more sophisticated explanation is that the [Pontryagin dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) of $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$, whereas the Pontryagin dual of the circle $\Bbb T$ is $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: How the **Pontryagin duality** explain the discrepancy of my question? @BenGrossmann I couldn't understand that concretely. Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: Let $\Bbb T$ denote the set of complex numbers with magnitude $1$. The fact that we need a coefficient for every element of $\Bbb Z$ in order to represent a periodic function over $[0,l]$ corresponds to the fact that the set of group homomorphisms from $[0,l]/0\sim l$ to $\Bbb T$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$. Similarly, the fact that we need a whole function over $\Bbb R$ in order to represent a function over $\Bbb R$ corresponds to the fact that the set of group homomorphisms from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb T$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$.